# Error in sending XML through Soap request

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have an XML file **soap2.xml** , which contains the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
        <BaseInfo>
                <TransId>P00C000-2017091907266</TransId>
                <UnitCode>23</UnitCode>
                <Camera_Slno>0077</Camera_Slno>
                <UserId>SYSTEM</UserId>
                <UserName>xyz</UserName>
                <ViolationDate>19-09-2017</ViolationDate>
                <ViolationTime>12:18:28</ViolationTime>
                <TimeStamp>1.5058e+09</TimeStamp>
                <VehicleNum>TN75WB5731</VehicleNum>
                <Violation>
                        <ViolationCode>05</ViolationCode>
                        <VehicleSpeed>0</VehicleSpeed>
                        <SpeedLimit></SpeedLimit>
                        <TransactionFiles>
                                <FrontalImage>http://10.77.1.36/P00C000-2017091907266.jpg;</FrontalImage>
                                <ContextImage></ContextImage>
                                <LPImage>http://10.77.1.36/P00C000-2017091907266_1.jpg</LPImage>
                                <ANPRVideo></ANPRVideo>
                                <ContextVideo></ContextVideo>
                        </TransactionFiles>
                </Violation>
        </BaseInfo>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And I am sending a soap request through following command :

```
curl -X POST -H "soapAction:''" --data @soap2.xml http://135.12.0.60:8080/ITMSeChallanGeneration/services/ITMSeChallanImpl?wsdl
```

I am getting following XML as response , it is showing some error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
            <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">Sunil</ns1:hostname>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have no idea whether it is format issue or request body issue or XML issue.
Any help will be appreciated. I am beginner to SOAP services so no idea of it.
I am using CentOS-7.2.

Comment: Can you post the schema?

Comment: This is all I have. I have no idea of what schema are you talking about ?

Comment: There should be an xsd file which specifies how the data you're sending in is supposed to be structured. The error suggests you've got a field somewhere it shouldn't be.